# CUPS TLS fatal alert error since upgrading to 18.04.2 - reposted due to previous bad format :(

Tags: networking, printing, samba

I have 2 Windows XP clients running lab equipment. These are Samba version 4.7.6 clients of Ubuntu 18.94.2 64-bit server running CUPS version 2.2.7. All has been working for some years, and the only changes are updates to Ubuntu and CUPS. To allow XP clients I have set `smb.conf` as shown below: I have noticed that the printer hangs and/or take hours to print. After a reboot, initially works OK but gets slower and slower as though a buffer is filling up or a similar bottleneck?

Looking at the CUPS error log I see these lines below appearing. The server and 2 XP workstations are not connected to the internet as they just run our own code in a local environment. Can anyone thrown me a lifeline?

**CUPS** - CUPS Error log:

```
E [10/May/2019:16:19:09 +0000] [Client 2] Unable to encrypt connection: A TLS fatal alert has been received. 
E [10/May/2019:16:19:30 +0000] [Client 8] Unable to encrypt connection: A TLS fatal alert has been received. 
E [10/May/2019:16:19:57 +0000] [Client 23] Unable to encrypt connection: A TLS fatal alert has been received. 
E [10/May/2019:16:19:57 +0000] [cups-deviced] PID 8878 (gutenprint52+usb) stopped with status 1! 
E [10/May/2019:16:19:59 +0000] [Client 29] Unable to encrypt connection: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
```

**Samba** - Global parameters:

```
[global]
add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g
add machine script = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u
add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u
bind interfaces only = Yes
client max protocol = SMB2
dns proxy = No
domain logons = Yes
interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 enp0s25
lanman auth = Yes
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
logon drive = H:
logon path = \%N\profiles\%U
logon script = %U.bat
map to guest = Bad User
max log size = 1000
ntlm auth = ntlmv1-permitted
os level = 64
pam password change = Yes
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
passwd chat = Enter\snew\s\spassword:* %n\n Retype\snew\s\spassword:* %n\n password\supdated\ssuccessfully .
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
security = USER
server role = classic primary domain controller
server string = %h
template shell = /bin/bash
unix password sync = Yes
usershare allow guests = Yes
wins support = Yes
workgroup = XXXXX3.LOCAL
rpc_daemon:spoolssd = fork
rpc_server:spoolss = external
idmap config * : backend = tdb

[homes]
browseable = No
comment = Home Directories
create mask = 0775
directory mask = 0775
read only = No
valid users = %S

[netlogon]
comment = Network Logon Service
guest ok = Yes
path = /srv/samba/netlogon

[profiles]
browseable = No
comment = Users profiles
create mask = 0600
directory mask = 0700
path = /srv/samba/profiles
read only = No

[printers]
browseable = No
comment = All Printers
create mask = 0700
guest ok = Yes
path = /var/spool/samba/
printable = Yes
use client driver = Yes
write list = @users

[print$]
comment = Printer Drivers
path = /var/lib/samba/printers
write list = @lpadmin
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful edits to my question Eliah, although an answer would have been more useful than an edit :)